# Show SQL result in horizontal format

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

All I want is to transform this:

```
Period  | Department    | Print | Copy
---------------------------------------
201601  | Dept 1        | 10    | 20
201601  | Dept 2        | 20    | 10
201602  | Dept 1        | 30    | 40
201602  | Dept 2        | 40    | 30
201603  | Dept 1        | 50    | 60
201603  | Dept 2        | 60    | 50
```

into this:

```
Department  | 201601 Print  | 201601 Copy   | 201602 Print  | 201602 Copy   | 201603 Print  | 201603 Copy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dept 1      | 10            | 20            | 30            | 40            | 50            | 60
Dept 2      | 20            | 10            | 40            | 30            | 60            | 50
```

I was trying to build the script with `PIVOT` but I don't know how to show both "Print" and "Copy" of each period in the columns.
Besides, since the values of 'Period' would be unknown therefore I cannot hard-code the value in the script as well.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT [Department]
    ,[201601] AS [201601 Copy]
    ,[201602] AS [201602 Copy]
    ,[201603] AS [201603 Copy]
FROM
    (SELECT [Copy], [Period], [Department] from #tempTable) AS ST
PIVOT
    (SUM([Copy]) FOR [Period] IN ([201601],[201602],[201603])) AS PT
```

And here is the script for creating the table with my sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tempTable
CREATE TABLE #tempTable(
    [Period] varchar(50)
    ,[Department] varchar(50)   
    ,[Print] int
    ,[Copy] int
)
INSERT INTO #tempTable VALUES 
     ('201601', 'Dept 1', 10, 20)
    ,('201601', 'Dept 2', 20, 10)
    ,('201602', 'Dept 1', 30, 40)
    ,('201602', 'Dept 2', 40, 30)
    ,('201603', 'Dept 1', 50, 60)
    ,('201603', 'Dept 2', 60, 50)
```

Thanks for any reply in advance.

**ANSWER**

I studied the answers received and finally build the below script:

```
DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max);
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT [Department],' + 
    STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT
            ',SUM(ISNULL(CASE [Period] WHEN ''' + [Period] + ''' THEN [Print] END, 0)) AS [' + [period] + ' Print]' +
            ',SUM(ISNULL(CASE [Period] WHEN ''' + [Period] + ''' THEN [Copy]  END, 0)) AS [' + [period] + ' Copy]'
        FROM #TempTable
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') +
    'FROM #TempTable 
    GROUP BY [Department]';
PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: Despite a superficial resemblance to a spreadsheet, SQL tables are very different beasts - rows and columns aren't generally interchangable. If this is purely for *presentation* purposes, it would be better to do this in the presentation/report layer, not the database.

Comment: Post your answer as such - an answer and accept it if you feel none of the offered answers solves your problem (better).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = 'select [Department],' + stuff((
    select distinct ',max(case [Period] when ' + char(39) + [Period] + char(39) + 
    ' then [Print] end) [' + [period] + ' Print]'
    + ',max(case [Period] when ' + char(39) + [Period] + char(39) + 
    ' then [Copy] end) [' + [period] + ' Copy]'
    from #TempTable
    for xml path('')
), 1, 1, '');

select @sql += ' from #TempTable group by [Department];';
exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, many thanks. I have edited a bit and shown my final script in my question.

Answer (score 5):

Another dynamic SQL that uses a pivot.
But this one uses a variable @Columns to generate a string with the column names.

```
declare @Columns varchar(max);
set  @Columns = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME([Period] +' Print') + ', ' + QUOTENAME([Period] +' Copy') FROM  #tempTable GROUP BY [Period] FOR  XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)') ,1,1,'');

declare @SQL varchar(max);
set @SQL = 'select *
from (
select [Department], [Period] + '' Print'' as Title, [Print] as Value from #tempTable
union all
select [Department], [Period] + '' Copy'' as Title, [Copy] as Value from #tempTable
) q
pivot (sum(Value) for Title in ('+ @Columns +')) p;';

--select @SQL;
exec (@SQL);
```

Comment: Thanks @LukStorms for your neat answer, but sorry that I chose Ullas' answer which only uses 1 variable. Wish I could choose both as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using ISNULL() and SUM() Functions.

```
SELECT [Department]
        ,SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN [Period]='201601' THEN [Print] END,0)) AS [201601 Print]
        ,SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN [Period]='201601' THEN Copy END,0)) AS [201601 Copy]
        ,SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN [Period]='201602' THEN [Print] END,0)) AS [201602 Print]
        ,SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN [Period]='201602' THEN Copy END,0)) AS [201602 Copy]
        ,SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN [Period]='201603' THEN [Print] END,0)) AS [201603 Print]
        ,SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN [Period]='201603' THEN Copy END,0)) AS [201603 Copy]               
FROM #tempTable
GROUP BY [Department]
```

Comment: Thanks for your clean and simple query, however the period values would be unknown, which required using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Department,SUM([201601Print])[201601 Print],SUM([201601Copy])[201601  Copy],SUM([201602Print])[201602 Print],
                 SUM([201602Copy])[201602 Copy],SUM([201603Print])[201603   Print],SUM([201603Copy])[201603 Copy] FROM (
SELECT [Department]
,[201601] AS [201601Copy]
,[201602] AS [201602Copy]
,[201603] AS [201603Copy]
,0 AS [201601Print]
,0 AS [201602Print]
,0 AS [201603Print]
FROM
(SELECT  [Period],[Copy], [Department] from #tempTable) AS ST
PIVOT
(SUM([Copy]) FOR [Period] IN ([201601],[201602],[201603])) AS PT
UNION ALL
SELECT [Department]
,0 AS [201601Copy]
,0 AS [201602Copy]
,0 AS [201603Copy]
,[201601] AS [201601Print]
,[201602] AS [201602Print]
,[201603] AS [201603Print]
FROM
(SELECT  [Period],[Print], [Department] from #tempTable) AS ST
PIVOT
(SUM([Print]) FOR [Period] IN ([201601],[201602],[201603])) AS PT
)A GROUP BY Department
```